# XML Schema from XML file for vb.net datatable

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datatable, xsd

Ok, so not even sure how to ask this, but I'm looking for help on how to create an XML schema file so that when a xml file is loaded into a dataset based on said schema, the data in the tables is as I expect it to be.

Here is the XML data:

```
<Cabinet>
   <Name>DANCE</Name>
   <MappedTypes>
      <TypeMapInfo>
         <TypeName>HIP HOP</TypeName>
         <DefaultInstitution />
         <DefaultAuthority>511</DefaultAuthority>
         <DefaultDocumentName />
      </TypeMapInfo>
      <TypeMapInfo>
         <TypeName>JITTERBUG</TypeName>
         <DefaultInstitution />
         <DefaultAuthority>511</DefaultAuthority>
         <DefaultDocumentName />
      </TypeMapInfo>
   </MappedTypes>
</Cabinet>
```

---

and basically, I would like it to show up like this in a datatable:

```
Cabinet      | Type Name | DefaultInstitution | DefaultAuthority | DefaultDocumentName
Dance        | HIP HOP   |                    | 511              |                    
Dance        | JITTERBUG |                    | 511              |
```

---

So Far this is what I have, but it only loads the first type name listed under the cabinet:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Cabinet">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <!--<xs:element name="MappedTypes"/>
      <xs:element name="TypeMapInfo"/>-->
      <xs:element  name="TypeName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultInstitution" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultAuthority" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultDocumentName" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: There are several sites where you can generate a schema from an instance. Once you have one, you can adjust it to your needs. This is one of them: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html Paste your XML there, and get the schema it generates. Use that to validate your data. After that you can change the types, add restrictions, etc.

Comment: I used visual studio to generate the XML schema. What I posted above is what visual studio made for me. However the data in the XML file is not loading the way I would like it too. What I'm looking for help in is how to make the schema produce the results that I have listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct your xsd if you want that your xml will be valid for it, probably your data table only is showing up the `<Name>` element because is the only element in the xsd which is well defined for your xml.

The following xsd fit your xml try with it:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://your_namespace" 
           targetNamespace="http://your_namespace" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="Cabinet" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="MappedTypes">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="TypeMapInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="TypeName" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="DefaultInstitution" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="DefaultAuthority" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
                                        <xs:element name="DefaultDocumentName" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

EDIT:

I review your question and reading your comments again I realize that maybe you're looking for a XML that fits your XSD instead of XSD that fits your XML as I respond in the first attempt. So If you have an XSD like:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Cabinet">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element  name="TypeName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultInstitution" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultAuthority" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
      <xs:element name="DefaultDocumentName" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

you must change your XML to:

```
<Cabinet>
 <Name>DANCE</Name>
 <TypeName>HIP HOP</TypeName>
 <DefaultInstitution/>
 <DefaultAuthority>511</DefaultAuthority>
 <DefaultDocumentName/>
</Cabinet>
<Cabinet>
 <Name>DANCE</Name>
 <TypeName>JITTERBUG</TypeName>
 <DefaultInstitution/>
 <DefaultAuthority>511</DefaultAuthority>
 <DefaultDocumentName/>
</Cabinet>
```

Hope this helps,